# Scrolling the scrollview in only horizontal not in vertical

Tags: iphone, ios

Thanks in advance. In my project am using paging and scrolling. but when i scrolling one page to another page we can able to scroll in horizontal, vertical and diagonally but i want to scroll only in horizontal direction only. Any one can suggest me.

Comment: UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 190, 300, 190)];

scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(300,350);

//it will scroll to only in vertical direction

Answer (score 0):

It will scroll vertically if you have its content size height set to more than actual height of scrollview height..

To remove vertical scrolling do this.

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(YourWidth,scrollview.frame.size.height);
```

you can also set

```
scrollview.bounces = NO ;
```

to remvoe Bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **`contentSize`** of **`UIScrollView`** such that the **width** of the **`contenSize`** is always equal to the **width** of the **`UIScrollView`**. Just vary the **height** of **`contentSize`**.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Xib->Select the Scrollview and Disable the Vertical Scrolling property in Xib file

Answer (score 0):

Disable vertical scrolling and set proper height (max is the height of the scrollview) for subviews in **all** the pages...